# How to check if element is half visible in the viewport with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following function to check if an element is visible or not in the viewport :

```
function elementInViewport(el) {
  let top = el.offsetTop;
  let left = el.offsetLeft;
  const width = el.offsetWidth;
  const height = el.offsetHeight;

  while (el.offsetParent) {
    el = el.offsetParent;
    top += el.offsetTop;
    left += el.offsetLeft;
  }

  return (
    top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight)
    && left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth)
    && (top + height) > window.pageYOffset
    && (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
  );
}
```

However, I want to check if an element is `50%` visible in the viewport. So if half of it is only showing, the check should return `true`. I know this is possible using the Intersection Observer API, however that is not an option for me as I want this to be compatible with `IE11`.

Comment: I want to fade out an element when it's 50% visible on top of the viewport.

Comment: I think `element.getBoundingClientRect()` can help.

Comment: You might want to check out the [intersection observer api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: There are [polyfills for IntersectionObserver](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill). Don't make the experience for all your users worse just because some of them use deprecated browsers

Comment: @Kaiido Good point. Will look into the polyfill. Apprecate it.

Answer (score 2):

This test will work for one direction (either horizontal or vertical).

```
function checkFifty(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top + (rect.height/2) > 0 && // top
        rect.left + (rect.width/2) > 0 && // left
        rect.top + (rect.height/2) < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && // bottom
        rect.left + (rect.width/2) < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) // right
    );
}
```

Note that the code that you copied to your question is not a good solution as it is very slow (and inaccurate). You should use `getBoundingClientRect` and you are done without any "manual" DOM traversal.

You can play around with this to see it in action:

```js
function checkFifty() {
    var el = document.getElementById("element");
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    console.log (
        // top
        rect.top + (rect.height/2) > 0 &&
        // left
        rect.left + (rect.width/2) > 0 &&
        // bottom
        rect.top + (rect.height/2) < (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        // right
        rect.left + (rect.width/2) < (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}

function showCoordinates() {
    var el = document.getElementById("element");
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    console.log(rect);
}
```

```css
#buttons {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
#container {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
}
#element {
  margin: 800px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
    <button onclick="showCoordinates()">coords</button>
    <button onclick="checkFifty()">check 50%</button>
    <p>scroll to the box and press the buttons. check the console output.</p>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```